# Better term for clergyperson?

Tags: terminology

I'm creating a database that will include many types of people, and am faltering on the best way to classify "clergypeople".  I'd prefer not to have separate entries for Deacon, Pastor, Priest, Preacher, Reverend, etc.  "Clergyperson" or "Clergy" seems technically ok, but I'm wondering if there's a more mainstream word that's just not coming to mind.

**Update:** Thanks all for the feedback.  The context is pretty simple, more or less just tags that can be associated with an individual, for example:

Architect, Builder, Athlete, Entertainer, Plantation Owner, Artist, etc.

At this point I'm leaning toward "Clergy", but a better synonym (that I don't want to use) would be "leader of church", i.e. I'm more concerned with aggregating the terms I originally listed above than including nuns/monks, etc.

As @Peter Turner pointed out, cleric is really the best fit, but it sounds too medieval for this application.

Thanks for all the input.  Ultimately, I think Clergy is going to work, so I'll accept that answer.  "Church Leader" is a little more specific than I originally asked for, but I'm going to consider using that as well...

Comment: Probably better on the English Language site.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback.  I think you're probably right, it would be better on the other site.  If a moderator can migrate that would be great.  Or I'll just re-ask it.  Thank you!

Comment: From a Christian perspective, many protestant denominations do not recognise 'clergy' as different from anyone else, and don't like to use the term.

Comment: There is such a broad diversity on this subject, even among Christians, I doubt an answer will be found that completely satisfies everyone. In my experience, *clergy* seems to be the generic term with the most common ground.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been hashed over before.

Comment: @HotLicks, link?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's wrong with just "clergy".   This is commonly used.

Also, what's the context?   For example, if you need to be general because you don't know the particular title in the context of a specific ceremony or event (e.g. a wedding) the commonly used term is "officiant".

Comment: Note: officiant can only refer to the person if they are *performing* the ceremony.  +1 nonetheless.

Comment: "Clergy" or "clergymen" would be the best answer here. Alternately, the synonymous phrase "men of the cloth" could be useful.

Comment: @RMac *clergymen/men of the cloth* might not be appropriate for females in this position.

Comment: No, but "clergy" refers to a group of clergymen (who run, say, a parish) collectively. "Clergymen" is the technically correct way to refer to a group of individuals which may not be completely representative of the leadership of a particular church. As for the matter of political correctness, if desired, you can adjust to say it as "clergypeople", "people of the cloth", "men and women of the cloth", or any similar variation.

Comment: *Clergypersonnel*?

Comment: What I meant is, I have commonly heard expressions like:   Who is the clergy performing your ceremony?      Maybe it is a relative neologism, but using 'clergy' as a genderless singular term in place of 'clergyperson', just like 'chair' instead of 'chairperson' is used.

Answer (score 6):

> See if "[**spiritual leader**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spiritual+leader)" fits in.
>
> - a leader in religious or sacred affairs
> - [man of the cloth](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/man+of+the+cloth)
>
> (**TFD**)

Comment: This is not a bad idea, but for the region I'm in (rural Louisiana) I think Church Leader would be a better fit.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the term you're looking for is [cleric](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cleric).

Comment: I don't think that term is used very commonly in this context.  I hear it used for the D&D archetype a lot (I play RPGs), and I hear it used to refer to people who do 'clerical work' a lot (which I think is incorrect, wouldn't clerk be the proper term?), but not to refer to real-life clergy/religious.

Comment: @the this question was migrated from christiantiy stackexchange, answer made more sense there.  But cleric is still a good general term. The term clerk descended from cleric and was pronounced the same "clerk" is the pronounciation.

Answer (score 3):

"**Religious Leader**" can typically be applied as a tag to any official leader of any group that calls itself a religion and has official leaders. It does seem a little more current and inclusive than "clergy", although either would typically be understood by any American consumers of your data.

Google search on this phrase turns up examples from Buddhism, Hinduism, Christianity, and Islam.

Comment: Not really appropriate for deacons.

Comment: Catholicism specifically seems to have made its own, narrower definition of "religious", which is in conflict with the definition used in most other situations. Unless this database is being used in a Catholic context, most people would likely consider a deacon a religious leader, despite the distinction.

Comment: I was objecting to the 'leader' part, not the 'religious' part.

Comment: At least in Protestant churches, deacons are basically lay members that have roles that are slightly clergy-like.  Same thing with elders.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, it would probably be "clergy" for the collective noun and "a member of the clergy" for the singular.  In the past, it would have been "Clergyman", but I'd not expect to hear that in current usage.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for the broad term which includes Nuns and Monks as well as Priests, the word you are looking for is religious.  This is derived from Catholic vocational theology.  This word is the one I've heard typically used by lay people but because of difficulty in analyzing usage due to the homographic adjective I can't get you a good citation for popularity.

The plural of religious is religious.

Examples:

"She's a religious"

"Our religious don't get the respect they deserve".

Comment: *Religious* or *regular* in the Catholic context refers to those bound to a rule, i.e. those belonging to religious institute or monastic order. But this excludes clergy who do not observe a rule. Thus, a Jesuit priest and a Dominican nun are *religious*, but a diocesan priest or deacon in this context is *secular*.

Comment: @choster Right, but that's not how I see people using the term.  The term is *commonly used* to mean basically a slightly broader version of clergy.  It's also used not just in a Catholic context.

Comment: I've never heard "religious" used (as an occupational label) outside a Catholic context - do you have an instance in mind?

Comment: @MattGutting http://arlife.org.uk/ , among others.  I haven't heard it outside a High Church context, but I have heard it/seen it used in Lutheran, Anglican, Orthodox, and (obviously) Catholic contexts.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I would say the term is *commonly used* to refer to anyone who lives as a faithful believer in the tenets of a religion— including people not of the cloth.

Comment: @choster that's as an adjective not a noun, at least as far as I've seen.